# Parsing JSON Array in Android into TextView

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I have the following JSON data, which is a JSON Array:

```
 {"Temperature":"26.10","Date":"2016-04-11 14:45:25"}
```

I've tried the below code be correct for parsing, however I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

```
  JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray (data);
  JSONArray tempArr = getArray("Temperature", jArr);
  String temp = jArr.getString("Temperature");
  TextView Temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTemp);
  Temp1.setText("Temperature: " + temp);
```

Edit: So I messed up and got it wrong, it's supposed to be a JSON Object

---

Comment: [Check here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) your **JSON** is valid or not

Comment: **which is a JSON Array:** your data doesn't look like `JsonArray`

Comment: [ {"Temperature":"26.10","Date":"2016-04-11 14:45:25"}]

Comment: begin with [ and end with ] is the jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely wrong.. Dear just see your json data .. Is a JSONObject not a json array. Is the correct way is like below

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject (data);

  String temp = json.optString("Temperature");
  String date = json.optString("Date");
  TextView Temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTemp);
  Temp1.setText("Temperature: " + temp);
```

Comment: Thank you, as this is one object, will I receive the temperature and date information?

Answer (score 0):

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            String temp = jsonObject.getString("Temperature");
            TextView Temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTemp);
            Temp1.setText("Temperature: " + temp);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Actually your data is not in JSONArray format it is in JSONObject formate so you require to parse with JSONObject

Comment: thank you, from this should I receive the temperature and date information as it is one object?

Answer (score 0):

As there are two objects with different name. So you have to access temperature and date information with different textview. It will look like as below:-

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject (data);

  String temp = json.optString("Temperature");
  String date = json.optString("Date");
  TextView Temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTemp);
  Temp1.setText("Temperature: " + temp);
  TextView Date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDate);
  Date1.setText("Date: " + date);
```